# Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined en la linea url: url + 'eliminar_contacto_empresa.php',

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, botón

```
function cargaPagina(pagina)
    {
      var desde = pagina * itemsPorPagina;
      $.ajax({
        data:{"param1":"dame","limit":itemsPorPagina,"offset":desde},
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"json",
        url:"Conexion_Contacto.php"
      }).done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){

        var lista = data.lista;

        $("#miTabla").html("");

        $.each(lista, function(ind, elem){


          $("<tr>"+

            '<td>'+elem.nombre_contacto_empresa+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+elem.telefono_contacto_empresa+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+elem.correo_contacto_empresa+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+elem.razon_social_empresa+'</td>'+
            '<td data-idpersona="'+elem.id_contacto_empresa+'">' +
            '<button class="btn btn-primary modalEdicion"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion">EDITAR</button> '+
            '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">ELIMINAR</button>'+'</td>'+
            '</tr>').appendTo($("#miTabla"));

        });     


      }).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,textError){
        alert("Error al realizar la peticion dame".textError);

      });



    $("body").on("click",".remove-item",function(){

        confirm('Eliminar Datos de la bbdd , ¿Esta seguro de eliminar este registro?');
        var idpersona = $(this).parent("td").data('data-idpersona');
        var c_obj = $(this).parents("tr");

        $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          type:"POST",
          url: url + 'eliminar_contacto_empresa.php',
          data:{idpersona:idpersona}
        }).done(function(data){
          c_obj.remove();
          toastr.success('Item Deleted Successfully.', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
          getPageData();
        });

      });


<?php

require 'Conectar_bbdd.php';

 $id = $_POST["data-idpersona"];

 echo "string".$id;


 $sql = "DELETE FROM contacto_empresa WHERE id_contacto_empresa =  '".$id."'";

 $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

 echo json_encode([$id]);

?>
```

Comment: **Error de escritura**: Aquí: `url: url + 'eliminar_contacto_empresa.php',`  intentas usar una variable `url` la cual no existe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tienes declarada la variable `url` en el evento clic.

Debes de declararla para que no te lanze el error:

```
$("body").on("click",".remove-item",function(){

  //..

    var url = "https://www.mipagina.com";

    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type:"POST",
      url: url + 'eliminar_contacto_empresa.php',
      data:{idpersona:idpersona}
    }).done(function(data){
      c_obj.remove();
      toastr.success('Item Deleted Successfully.', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
      getPageData();
    });

});
```

O eliminas el uso de la variable no declarada:

```
$("body").on("click",".remove-item",function(){

    //..

    $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          type:"POST",
          url: '/eliminar_contacto_empresa.php',
          data:{idpersona:idpersona}
    }).done(function(data){
          c_obj.remove();
          toastr.success('Item Deleted Successfully.', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
          getPageData();
    });

});
```

Recuerda que siempre que encuentres el error `undefined`, es porque estas intentando acceder aun objeto que nunca fue declarado.

Comment: aun sigo teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: Te sigue lanzando el error `uncaugth reference error`? O es otro error?

Comment: Einer no hace nada

Comment: <?php

require 'Conectar_bbdd.php';

 $id = $_POST["idpersona"];

 echo "string".$id;


 $sql = "DELETE FROM contacto_empresa WHERE id_contacto_empresa =  '".$id."'";

 $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

 echo json_encode([$id]);
 
?>

Comment: ese es el archivo de php, de eliminar_contacto_empresa.php

Comment: Deberias de formular otra pregunta para poder responder. Esta pregunta era acerca de javascript.

Comment: defini url, pero no me hace nada y en la inspeccion en el buscador tampoco me arroja errores, como puedo saber si la  var idpersona = $(this).parent("td").data('idpersona');, esta realmente me esta obteniendo la id de la tabla?

Answer (score 1):

En el AJAX estás llamando un archivo PHP al cuál le antecede una cadena de texto 'url', sin embargo no veo que esté definida como var url = "root/carpeta".

```
url: url + 'eliminar_contacto_empresa.php',
```

Puedes declarar la variable url local o globalmente:

```
var url = "dominio.com/";
...
url: url + 'eliminar_contacto_empresa.php',
```

O bien, elimina la variable url de tu parámetro ajax, y pon todo dentro de la misma cadena que llama al archivo PHP:

```
url: 'eliminar_contacto_empresa.php',
```

Comment: @Shaz aun sigo teniendo el mismo problema, no me deja eliminar